# Execute a command file in jBPM

Tags: java, jboss, workflow, drools, jbpm

Is there any direct support (Asset) to run a batch file in jBPM.

I know that I can run Java code like below.

[image]

This is the java code I am trying to run.

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Files\\Test.bat");
    Process p = pb.start();
    int exitStatus = p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Execution Done. Status: "+exitStatus);
```

I am curious to if there is a direct way to run a Batch file directly without writing Java code manually.

Comment: I would be extremely concerned if arbitrary code was allowed to be executed in a non-sandbox context.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of how to execute the batch file but maybe you can try with
[executing the shell script using work item handler](https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm-work-items/blob/master/exec-workitem/src/main/java/org/jbpm/process/workitem/exec/ExecShellScriptWorkItemHandler.java).

Comment: Thanks I am using Exec WorkItemHandler. The problem is to get the exitCode from that Handler.